# Iterate a query with an external parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am develop a e commerce site.

Here the code for pass parameter from shopping cart (data table) to Order database.

```
        Dim con As SqlConnection
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=NBK012\ARPASQL;Initial Catalog=aCommerceDB;Integrated Security=True")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [aOrdini] (ID,NomeProdotto,PrezzoProdotto,Quantità,NumeroOrdine) values(@ID,@NomeProdotto,@PrezzoProdotto,@Quantità,@NumeroOrdine)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomeProdotto", GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoProdotto", GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantità", GridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroOrdine", TextBox9.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

And this work fine but only with one item in the shopping cart.
First question, how can i iterate that code ? so as pass all the shopping cart to order db.
The second thing is that the order number arrive from another database that i use as counter.
So i don't need to iterate the order number because all item in shopping cart has the same shopping number

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert all the rows in your GridView to the database, you would put your insert code inside [a For loop](https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-vbnet):

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=NBK012\ARPASQL;Initial Catalog=aCommerceDB;Integrated Security=True")
con.Open()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [aOrdini] (ID,NomeProdotto,PrezzoProdotto,Quantità,NumeroOrdine) values(@ID,@NomeProdotto,@PrezzoProdotto,@Quantità,@NumeroOrdine)", con)

For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomeProdotto", GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrezzoProdotto", GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantità", GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeroOrdine", TextBox9.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
Next

con.Close()
```

A few things to point out about this code:

- See that I'm using "`.Rows(i)`" inside the loop, instead of "`.Rows(1)`" in order to get the Cell values from each row as the loop progresses
- Notice that the parameters collection is cleared at the end of each loop iteration.  This is to prevent duplicate parameters from being added, which is not allowed
- Note that connection is only opened once, and then closed once, rather than opening and closing inside the loop.  This is a more efficient, but it does leave the connection open for a long time if you have many, many rows

Comment: Thanks for the answer man but the output is all row as the first.

Comment: Exscuseme, i forgot   .Rows(i)    , now it's work fine.
Thank you very much !